# Keep Viewport Resolution And Scale It's Contents To Fit The Window?

Tags: c, opengl, sdl, sdl-2, glfw

Recently I've found the `SDL2` function [SDL_RenderSetLogicalSize](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderSetLogicalSize), which does [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbov5.png) with the black bars.

It:

1. Allows for the resizing of a window and...
2. As it's resized, `SDL` maintains the viewport's original resolution
   and..
3. `SDL` Scales it's contents to best fit the window.

Since `SDL`'s backend is in OpenGL, How could one implement the same functionality within **OpenGL** and **GLFW**?

Comment: You can set the viewport with [`glViewport`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es2.0/xhtml/glViewport.xml).

Comment: And you can render to an FBO